# How does a package run without all the dependencies being installed on the target system?

Tags: software-installation, subversion

I am trying to build the latest version of `subversion` on ubuntu 12.10 and was having some trouble completing `./configure` as I seemed to be getting a never ending stream of `configure: error: x not found` messages. I installed `apr` and supplied the paths to the `apr-1-config` file to get rid of the first, then I installed `sqlite` etc. and currently I am working on `configure: error: Expat not found`.

Prior to attempting an install of `1.7.7`, I had just used `apt-get install subversion` which installed `1.7.5` and was working fine. My question is, why does `1.7.5` work on my machine if I didn't have `sqlite`, `apr` and all the other dependencies that seem to be needed now that I'm it from the source? does `1.7.5` not have such dependencies or were they installed during my `apt-get` command and I just needed to link to them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some distributions (including Ubuntu) separate packages that contain libraries into two packages: one containing the files needed to *run* programs that use the library, and a `-dev` package containing the files needed to *compile* programs that use the library.  So what you're really missing are the various `-dev` packages to go with the libraries that Subversion needs.  When you `apt-get install subversion`, it installs the libraries, but not the header files and other compile-time-only bits.

For example, installing [subversion](http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/subversion) on Ubuntu 12.10 will install [libsqlite3-0](http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/libsqlite3-0), but not [libsqlite3-dev](http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/libsqlite3-dev).

Running `apt-get build-dep subversion` should install the necessary `-dev` packages for you.

Comment: I have successfully installed `1.7.7` using the `-dev` package from `apt-get` which would be for `1.7.5`, I'm assuming. Might there be issues using different `-dev` and source packages together?

Comment: @stariz77, `apt-get build-dep` will install the `-dev` packages for the libraries needed by the package you give it.  If a newer version has added new dependencies, they won't be installed, and you'll have to figure out which packages to install manually.  But for a minor release (like from 1.7.5 to 1.7.7) that's not usually an issue.